# render same component twice with different props from ajax-result

Tags: javascript, reactjs

does anyone has any idea, why the second data is always empty?

Component A

```
...
render () {
   return (
       <ComponentB data={list1} />
       <div />
       ...
       <ComponentB data={list2} />
   );
}
componentDidMount() {
    $.ajax({
        url: url1,
        method: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function(response1) {
            $.ajax({
                url: url2,
                method: 'GET',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function(response2) {
                     this.setState({
                         list1: response1,
                         list2: response2
                     })
                 },
                 error: function(error) {
                     console.log(error);
                 }
            });
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });       
}
...
```

I'm always getting an empty data prop of the second ComponentB. 
In ComponentA I can see that the states list1 and list2 having content. But only the list1 ist set in ComponentB :-/

Comment: In `<ComponentB data={list} />`, where does `list` come from?

Comment: Oh sry! I mean list1, just updated my question

Comment: I see. Normally, I don't include jQuery in React project anymore. For this type of problem, I would suggest to use async... await syntax, eg: `async componentDidMount() { const res1 = await axios(...); const res2 = await axios(...); this.setState(...)}`

Comment: 1. I have to use jquery! 2. the state is well set in ComponentA. I think the problem does nothing have to do with the didcomponent